# https redirect in .htaccess using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This works awesome for me in that it redirects www.domain.com and domain.com to https://www.domain.com

My problem is that subdomains like sub.domain.com now are redirected there as well.  How do I keep the existing functionality but NOT affect the subdomains?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a restriction:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` line will make sure only hosts `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` get redirected.